# REACT JS and SCSS SASS error: variable undefined variable

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, sass

installed required packages:
node-SASS
bootstrap-5
The error is:
Compiled with problems:
ERROR in ./src/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[3]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[7].use[4]!./src/index.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js): SassError: Undefined variable: "$fontFamily". on line 2 of src/styles/sass/_body.scss from line 33 of src/index.scss >> font-family: $fontFamily; ---------------^
---------------------_body.scss----------------------------------

```
 body {
  font-family: $fontFamily;
  font-size: $fontSize;
  line-height: $lineHeight;
  letter-spacing: $letterSpacing;
  color: $colorText;
  background: $colorBackground;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

// close all the scroll bars
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
}

// Selection color
::selection {
  background: rgba($colorPrimary, 0.3);
}

// default link options
a {
  transition: none;
  color: $colorPrimary;
  outline: 0 !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  &:hover,
  &:active,
  &:focus {
    outline: 0 !important;
    color: $colorPrimary;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
button {
  outline: 0 !important;
  &:hover,
  &:active,
  &:focus {
    outline: 0 !important;
  }
}

// Safearea
$safeBottom: env(safe-area-inset-bottom);
$safeTop: env(safe-area-inset-top);
```

Comment: Please show us the code where `$fontFamily` is called.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/15832899/baptiste-rieber   updated the post with required code.

Comment: And where does `$fontFamily` comes from?

Comment: @Arkellys  $fontFamily is coming from _theme-setting.scss and i have imported it to index.scss error got resolved but now getting new error: ./src/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./src/index.scss)
Module not found: Can't resolve './inc/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css' in 'C:\Users\kaush\Desktop\WTS_THEME_SCSS\test-template-scss\src'
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

Comment: Just read the error... `Module not found: Can't resolve './inc/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css'` so you're not importing this file correctly.